# Angular 2 Routed apps hosted in iframes

Tags: angular, outlook-addin, angular2-routing

I am currently working on an Outlook add-in that I am building with Angular 2.
Because it's an outlook hosted app, it will be run in a cross domain iframe and there is nothing that I can change about this. The iframe is also sandboxed with the following properties `allow-scripts allow-forms allow-same-origin ms-allow-popups allow-popups`.

I am trying to use Angular 2's router, but whenever I use the `navigate` method, I get a series of exceptions stating `this._history.pushState is not a function`. I tried both the default location strategy as well as the hash location strategy and get this exception with both. I thought the purpose of `HashLocationStrategy` was to support older browsers that don't fully support HTML 5. It seems like that defeats the purpose with using the HTML 5 `history` methods such as pushState, but I may be wrong in my understanding of the differences between `LocationStrategy` and `HashLocationStrategy`

My question is, is there a way to tell the router not to use `history.pushState` or anything else that can be done so that I can use the router in this iframe. Because I am getting these exceptions, it is stopping some of my application startup code from executing.

EDIT: As a side note, my application has multiple pages, so it is definitely not a strict SPA. I was trying to keep the entire UI as a static site and using the router to navigate between the pages. I don't necessarily care about preserving navigation history since it is hosted in outlook, so maybe the angular router doesn't fit my use case. I am also researching the idea of using something like ASP.NET MVC for the entire app, but using angular to power each section/page of the application.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't due because of the iFrame it is Office.js that sets window.history.replaceState() and window.history.pushState() to null. The easiest way to stop this breaking the router is to set them to empty functions like in the snippet below, then you can safely use the HashLocationStrategy.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>office add-in</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    ...
    <script>
        window.history.replaceState = function(){};
        window.history.pushState = function(){};
    </script>
    ...
</head>

<body>
    <addin></addin>
</body>

</html>
```

I've have a code sample on MSDN [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Building-an-Office-add-in-a9d506cd) which has working routing.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own `LocationStrategy`.

You can use the source for `HashLocationStrategy` as template. It's not very complicated https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/router/location/hash_location_strategy.ts

To make Angular use your custom `LocationStrategy` add it to providers after `ROUTER_PROVIDERS`

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS, 
    provide(LocationStrategy, {useValue: CustomLocationStrategy})]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem trying to get Angular 2 routing to work. Both with the RC1 router and the deprecated router. Gunter's suggestion was a winner, I was already using the HashLocationStrategy. I found the latest source code for this class on GitHub, created my own custom location strategy based on it and simply removed the lines that tried to update the web browser history when routing occurred. This stopped the errors from happening and this fix works for both the deprecated router and it's newer replacement.

I wrote up a quick blog post that goes through those steps in a bit more detail for those who are interested:
https://camerondwyer.wordpress.com/2016/06/17/getting-the-angular-2-router-working-for-an-office-addin/

Comment: It would be great if you could post the essential parts of the code in the answer directly.